# How to use AlertDialog.builder into clickable link?

Tags: java, android, hyperlink

example of my code to make qr code scanner

if (result.getContents() !=null)

```
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
                builder.setTitle("result");
                builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
                builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AlertDialog.Builder class to create a clickable link like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
 builder.setMessage("Click here to visit the website") .setCancelable(false) 
 .setPositiveButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public 
 void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { Intent browserIntent = new 
 Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.website.com")); 
 startActivity(browserIntent); } }); AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
 alert.show();
```

Comment: is it possible to get a clickable link after getting the result? after scan a code

Comment: or is it possible to make the results.getContents() into clickable link. instead of having fix link